# How get full pathname in git log --stat

Tags: git

In `git log --stat` when the file's pathname is too long, it will abbreviate to `...`

for example:

```
.../folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/file1   |  28++++
```

if I use `--name-status` or `--name-only`, I can get the full pathname but missing the line changing information.

So how to get the full pathname as well as the line changing information at the same time?

Comment: Try running `git status --porcelain`, and if that doesn't meet your needs, I can reopen your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to get the full filenames and corresponding line change from each commit in log. I think `git status` is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --stat=260 --stat-graph-width=80
```

Here 260 is the maximum width for both the path and the graph (+ and -).  260 should be a proper width for most paths and you can pick another number if necessary. But it's a bit too long for the graph, so here use --stat-graph-width=80 to limit its width individually.